# Intersection points of two-variable polynomials

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, polynomials, intersection

Let $h$ and $g$ designate two multivariable polynomials:

$$\!\!h(x,y)=-96\! \left(32 x^2\!+\!8 x (3\!-\!8 y)\!+\!40 y^2-28 y+5\right) \left(10 x^2+x (4 y-2)+\quad\quad\quad\\ \quad\quad+(1-2 y)^2\right) \left(52 x^2+4 x (34 y-35)+352 y^2-244 y+43\right)$$

$$\!g(x,y)=\!320 x^4\!+\!176 x^3\!+\!\left(-512\! x^3\!-\!184 x^2\!-\!84 x\!-\!48\right)\! y\!+\!\left(272 x^2\!+\!160 x\!+\!172\right)\! y^2\!+\!\\+34 x^2+(-96 x-272) y^3+14 x+160 y^4+5 $$

Both functions intersect at $(-1/8,1/4)$ and $(0,1/2)$.
Nevertheless, it is of my interest to obtain those points using *Mathematica*.
That is to say, I want to determine the common or the intersection points between $g(x,y)$ and $h(x,y)$.

I have attempted to find those points using `ContourPlot`, as may see below:

```
h = -96 (5 + 32x^2 + 8x (3 - 8y) - 28y + 40y^2) ( 10x^2 + (1 - 2 y)^2
    + x (-2 + 4y)) ( 43 + 52x^2 - 244y + 352y^2 + 4x ( -35 + 34y));

g = 5 + 14x + 34x^2 + 176x^3 + 320x^4 + ( -48 - 84x - 184x^2 - 512x^3) y
   + ( 172 + 160x + 272x^2) y^2 + ( -272 - 96x) y^3 + 160y^4;

plot = ContourPlot[ h == g, {h, -2, 2}, {g, -2, 2}, 
         MaxRecursion -> 4, PlotPoints -> 50] // Quiet; 

intersectionpoints = plot[[1]][[1]][[1]]
```

However, it did not return the intersection points.

Based on the above, how may I properly obtain the common points between $h(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ by employing *Mathematica*?

Comment: Does `Solve[g == h]` do what you need, or do you need something else? What about `Solve[g == h, {x, y}, Reals] // FullSimplify` for forcing real values? I'm not sure I understand what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi,@Roman. I hope you doing well. Actually, I want the intersection points of $h(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$. I will try your suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Should be `{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}` instead of `{h, -2, 2}, {g, -2, 2}`

Comment: Are you in the real or the complex domain? Both domain are reducable; in the complex domain, complex paths result. If you do not tell Mathematica to work in the real domain, then it works in the complex domain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We define:

```
h[x_, y_] := -96 (5 + 32 x^2 + 8 x (3 - 8 y) - 28 y + 40 y^2) (10 x^2 + (1 - 2 y)^2 
             + x (-2 + 4 y)) (43 + 52 x^2 - 244 y + 352 y^2 + 4 x (-35 + 34 y))
g[x_, y_] :=  5 + 14 x + 34 x^2 + 176 x^3 + 320 x^4 
             + (-48 - 84 x - 184 x^2 - 512 x^3) y + (172 + 160 x + 272 x^2) y^2 
             + (-272 - 96 x) y^3 + 160 y^4
```

The most powerful function you can use is `Reduce`

```
Reduce[g[x, y] == h[x, y] && -1 < x < 3 && -2 < y < 2, {x, y}]
```

> ```
>  (x == -(1/8) && y == 1/4) || (x == 0 && y == 1/2) || 
>  (x == (4086 - Sqrt[16476801])/3420 && y == 1/176 (61 
>         - (17 (4086 - Sqrt[16476801]))/1710) - 1/352 Sqrt[
>            1/3 (-767 + 2724/95 (4086 - Sqrt[16476801]) - 
>             1/285 (4086 - Sqrt[16476801])^2)]) || 
>  ((4086 - Sqrt[16476801])/3420 < x < (4086 + Sqrt[16476801])/3420 && 
>    ( y == 1/176 (61 - 34 x) - Sqrt[-767 + 98064 x - 41040 x^2]/(352 Sqrt[3]) ||
>     y == 1/176 (61 - 34 x) + Sqrt[-767 + 98064 x - 41040 x^2]/(
>       352 Sqrt[3]))) || (x == (4086 + Sqrt[16476801])/3420 && 
>     y == 1/176 (61 - (17 (4086 + Sqrt[16476801]))/1710) 
>           - 1/352 Sqrt[1/3 (-767 + 2724/95 (4086 + Sqrt[16476801]) 
>           - 1/285 (4086 + Sqrt[16476801])^2)])
> ```

```
   Reduce[g[#, y] == h[#, y] && -2 < y < 2, {y}] & /@ {-1/8, 0}}]
```

> ```
>   {y == 1/4, y == 1/2}
> ```

If we take a closer look at contours of functions it appears that the both points $(-\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{4})$ and $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ are global minima of $g$

```
Minimize[{g[x, y], #}, {x, y}] & /@ {x < 0, x >= 0}
```

> ```
> {{0, {x -> -(1/8), y -> 1/4}}, {0, {x -> 0, y -> 1/2}}}
> ```

```
RegionPlot[{g[x, y] < 1/50, g[x, y] < 1/117, g[x, y] < 1/150},
  {x, -1/5, 1/10}, {y, 1/10, 3/5}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{{-1/8, 1/4}, {0, 1/2}}]},
  Axes -> True]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[
  Evaluate@Table[h[x, y] == c, {c, {0, -1, -4, -5, -10}}],
  {x, -1/6, 1/14}, {y, 1/5, 11/20}, ContourStyle -> Thick,
  PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 5, Axes -> True, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{{-1/8, 1/4}, {0, 1/2}}]}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{h == 0, h == -1, h == -4, h == -5, h == -10},
                         {Left, Top}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
h = -96 (5 + 32 x^2 + 8 x (3 - 8 y) - 28 y + 
    40 y^2) (10 x^2 + (1 - 2 y)^2 + x (-2 + 4 y)) (43 + 52 x^2 - 
    244 y + 352 y^2 + 4 x (-35 + 34 y));
g = 5 + 14 x + 34 x^2 + 176 x^3 + 
    320 x^4 + (-48 - 84 x - 184 x^2 - 512 x^3) y + (172 + 160 x + 
    272 x^2) y^2 + (-272 - 96 x) y^3 + 160 y^4;

Solve[g == h, {x, y}, Reals] // FullSimplify
```

> During evaluation of In[27]:= Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.

```
(*    {{y -> ConditionalExpression[(366 - 204 x - Sqrt[3] Sqrt[-767 + 432 (227 - 95 x) x])/1056,
               Sqrt[16476801] + 3420 x > 4086 && 3420 x < 4086 + Sqrt[16476801]]},
       {y -> ConditionalExpression[(366 - 204 x + Sqrt[3] Sqrt[-767 + 432 (227 - 95 x) x])/1056,
               Sqrt[16476801] + 3420 x > 4086 && 3420 x < 4086 + Sqrt[16476801]]},
       {x -> -1/8, y -> 1/4},
       {x -> 0, y -> 1/2},
       {x -> (4086 - Sqrt[16476801])/3420, y -> 11/95 + (17 Sqrt[499297/33])/9120},
       {x -> (4086 + Sqrt[16476801])/3420, y -> 11/95 - (17 Sqrt[499297/33])/9120}}    *)
```

Note that

```
Factor[g - h]
(*    (1 - 2 x + 10 x^2 - 4 y + 4 x y + 4 y^2) *
      (5 + 24 x + 32 x^2 - 28 y - 64 x y + 40 y^2) *
      (4129 - 13440 x + 4992 x^2 - 23424 y + 13056 x y + 33792 y^2)    *)
```

$g-h$ can be factorized and the factors can be analyzed separately:

```
e1 = {x, y - 1/2} . {{10, 2}, {2, 4}} . {x, y - 1/2};
e2 = {x + 1/8, y - 1/4} . {{32, -32}, {-32, 40}} . {x + 1/8, y - 1/4};
e3 = {x - 227/190, y - 11/95} . {{474240/499297, 620160/499297}, {620160/499297, 3210240/499297}} . {x - 227/190, y - 11/95};

g - h == 499297/95 * e1 * e2 * (e3 - 1) // Expand
(*    True    *)
```

- The first factor, `e1 == 0`, is zero at the point $\left(0,\frac12\right)$
- The second factor, `e2 == 0`, is zero at the point $\left(-\frac18,\frac14\right)$
- The third factor, `e3 == 1`, is zero on an ellipse

Graphically,

```
DensityPlot[g - h, {x, -1, 3}, {y, -1, 1},
            MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0, 10}}, 
            Epilog -> {Red, Point /@ {{0, 1/2}, {-(1/8), 1/4}}},
            AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Zoom in a bit:

```
DensityPlot[g - h, {x, -0.2, 0.2}, {y, 0.2, 0.6}, 
            MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {Range[0, 10]}, 
            Epilog -> {Red, Point /@ {{0, 1/2}, {-(1/8), 1/4}}}, 
            AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Comment: Could you check if points lie on the solution set `ContourPlot[h[x, y] == g[x, y], {x, -1/2, 5/2}, {y, -3/4, 3/4}, ContourStyle -> Thick, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 5,  Axes -> True, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{{-1/8, 1/4}, {0, 1/2}}]}]`. On my system they don't (ver. 13.0.1).  I can't find a mistake. `h` and `g` are definded as in my answer.  I mean there must be a bug in `ContourPlot` since  contour lies only for $x>=0$ while there is a solution `{-1/8,1/4}`.

Comment: `ContourPlot` won't find single points reliably. It only finds **contours** properly.

Comment: I know, I've added points $(-1/8,1/4)$ and $(0,1/2)$ with `Epilog` to `ContourPlot`.  They are outside of contour $g(x,y)=h(x,y)$.

Comment: I've added some contour plots that show what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Factoring shows they contain common factors.

```
Factor[g]

(* Out[626]= (1 - 2 x + 10 x^2 - 4 y + 4 x y + 4 y^2) (5 + 24 x + 
   32 x^2 - 28 y - 64 x y + 40 y^2) *)

Factor[h]

(* Out[627]= -96 (1 - 2 x + 10 x^2 - 4 y + 4 x y + 4 y^2) (5 + 24 x + 
   32 x^2 - 28 y - 64 x y + 40 y^2) (43 - 140 x + 52 x^2 - 244 y + 
   136 x y + 352 y^2) *)
```

So it suffices to find where the quotient is unity.

```
ss = 
 Simplify[
  Solve[(43 - 140 x + 52 x^2 - 244 y + 136 x y + 352 y^2) == -1/96, x]]

(* Out[630]= {{x -> 
   1/624 (840 - 816 y - 
      Sqrt[6] Sqrt[63923 + 76032 y - 328320 y^2])}, {x -> 
   1/624 (840 - 816 y + Sqrt[6] Sqrt[63923 + 76032 y - 328320 y^2])}} *)
```

Check that they are equal on this set.

```
In[633]:= h/g /. ss // Simplify

(* Out[633]= {1, 1} *)
```

Other solutions can be obtained by solving for where each of the remaining two factors vanishes.